# AFNetworking 2.0 Add batch of AFHTTPRequestOperation objects to AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In the AFNetworking 2.0 library, how do I add AFHTTPRequestOperation objects to a AFHTTPRequestOperationManager ? Should I create a bunch of AFHTTPRequestOperation and add them directly to the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's operation queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the manager will creat operation by itself with parameters we passed, and return the operation to us. You could have a look at the methods which return a AFHTTPRequestOperation in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h file.

Comment: Do all these methods start the operation as soon as you call them though? I need to set dependancies before the operations start executing.